# Failed to resolve: com.github.unsplash:unsplash-photopicker-android:1.0.1

Tags: android, gradle

I was trying to make a new project starting with dependencies when I got this:

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.unsplash:unsplash-photopicker-android:1.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/unsplash/unsplash-photopicker-android/1.0.1/unsplash-photopicker-android-1.0.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/unsplash/unsplash-photopicker-android/1.0.1/unsplash-photopicker-android-1.0.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

I tried to implement this library as mentioned here: https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-photopicker-android, so I also included maven repo like this:

```
repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

I have no idea why this error occured and would be happy if you can help me!

Whole build.gradle (app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.garvardinho.nwcode"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // androidx
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'

    // moxy
    implementation 'com.github.moxy-community:moxy:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.github.moxy-community:moxy-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.github.moxy-community:moxy-androidx:2.2.2'
    kapt 'com.github.moxy-community:moxy-compiler:2.2.2'

    // cicerone
    implementation 'com.github.terrakok:cicerone:7.1'

    // material
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'

    // gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'

    // okhttp
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:5.0.0-alpha.3'

    // picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    // retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava3:2.9.0'

    // rxjava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.1.5'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'

    // dagger
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.42'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.42'

    // unsplash
    implementation 'com.github.unsplash:unsplash-photopicker-android:1.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: can you add build.gradle(app level) file code

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb, I also haven't found this unsplash repo on jitpack - maybe that's the case. If so - what is the steps to get this lib without cloning explicitly?