# Failed to resolve in gradle, Unsplash photo picker android studio

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to implement Unsplash API according to this website:

> https://unsplash.com/documentation#creating-a-developer-account

But got stuck pretty quickly. I don't know why Gradle refuses to compile so here are some files:

#### `build.gradle (Project)`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.5.2"
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

#### `build.gradle (App)`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id "kotlin-parcelize"
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gallery"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    namespace 'com.example.gallery'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"

    // Unsplash 
    implementation 'com.github.unsplash:unsplash-photopicker-android:1.0.1'

    // Kotlin
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3")
    // tests
    testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3"
    testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.8'
}
```

All I try to do is to add those lines (from the GitHub specification):

> To integrate UnsplashPhotoPicker into your Android Studio project
> using Gradle, specify in your project build.gradle file:
>
> allprojects {    repositories {
> ...
> maven { url  'https://jitpack.io' }    } } And in your app module build.gradle file, replacing x.y.x by the latest tag:
>
> dependencies {    implementation
> 'com.github.unsplash:unsplash-photopicker-android:x.y.z' }

The problem occured(8 similar problem):

> Execution failed for task ':gallery:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
>
> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':gallery:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> > Could not find com.github.unsplash:unsplash-photopicker-android:1.0.1.
> > Searched in the following locations:
> > - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/unsplash/unsplash-photopicker-android/1.0.1/unsplash-photopicker-android-1.0.1.pom
> > - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/unsplash/unsplash-photopicker-android/1.0.1/unsplash-photopicker-android-1.0.1.pom
> > Required by:
> > project :gallery

This question was asked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73023133/failed-to-resolve-com-github-unsplashunsplash-photopicker-android1-0-1) but got no answer...

Answer (score 0):

Add the

> maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

in **setting.gradle(project level)**

```
   dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
        repositories {
           //...
   maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    
        }
    }
```

[image]